# Integration taking too long

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica is having issues with the following code:

```
AreaH = Integrate[Integrate[\[Sqrt](a*Sin[\[Theta]]^2 - J^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^4), {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}], {\[Phi], 0, 2*\[Pi]}]
SEn = AreaH/4;
Plot[SEn, {J, 0, 100}]
```

It is stuck attempting to do the integral and so doesn't output the solution. How can I re-code this to actually make it produce the solutions I want?

Comment: Edit - I simplified it down significantly to just the integral

Comment: If the integrand does not depend on $\phi$ this is a line-integral. `= 2 \[Pi] Integrate[\[Sqrt](a*Sin[\[Theta]]^2 - J^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^4), {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` and `J` are real and positive, then this gives a partial result:

```
Integrate[√(a*Sin[θ]^2 - J^2*Sin[θ]^4),
  {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2*π},
  Assumptions -> a > 0 && J > 0]
(*
ConditionalExpression[
   2*Pi*(Sqrt[a] + (a/J - J)*
          ArcCosh[Sqrt[a/(a - J^2)]]), a > J^2]
*)
```

Comment: I also did get this eventually, but only after my Notebook spent a solid 5 mins computing it. Why is this so slow?

Comment: @Sophia It takes my MacBook Pro only 13 sec.  It takes some time to analyze singularities that depend on parameters (on `a` and `J` in this case).  I'm not sure what yours takes so much longer than mine.  It could be a version difference.  I'm using V12.2.

Comment: This is two seconds faster: `Integrate[\[Sqrt](a*Sin[\[Theta]]^2 - J^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^4), {\[Theta],  0, Pi/2, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*\[Pi]}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && J > 0 && a > J^2]`

Comment: Really odd. I have a custom built computer that I know has really good specs. I wonder if it being throttled for some reason. I will try the second version you posted too! Thank you!